# Need help converting hex string to time in C#

Tags: string, time, hex, type-conversion

I have issues understanding how to convert a hex value to a duration.

Here are some examples I've seen in the case I study:

```
2b3da = 2:44.986
2bf64 = 2:47.868
2c84a = 2:50.074
```

Could someone help to understand how those results are reached ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide any context?  Where is this data coming from?  This could be any kind of custom encoding.

Comment: Might be, this is part of a UDP packet sent over network. It's related basically to a racing game and contains finish time.
Someone did succeed converting this (which is how I came with those results) but I couldn't contact him so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
string hex1;
string[] hex = new string[16];
hex[0] = hex1.Substring(0, 2);       
hex[1] = hex1.Substring(2, 2);
hex[2] = hex1.Substring(4, 2);
hex[3] = hex1.Substring(6, 2);
hex[4] = hex1.Substring(8, 2);
hex[5] = hex1.Substring(10, 2);
hex[6] = hex1.Substring(12, 2);
hex[7] = hex1.Substring(14, 2);
//WE DONOT NEED TO REVERSE THE STRING

//CONVERTING TO INT SO WE CAN ADD TO THE BYTE[]
int[] decValue = new int[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    decValue[i] = Convert.ToInt32(hex[i], 16);
}

//CONVERTING TO BYTE BEFORE WE CAN CONVERT TO UTC 
byte[] timeByte = new byte[8];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    timeByte[i] = (byte)decValue[i];

    DateTime convertedTime = ConvertWindowsDate(timeByte);
    textBox7.Text = convertedTime.ToString();    
}

public static DateTime ConvertWindowsDate(byte[] bytes)
{
    if (bytes.Length != 8) throw new ArgumentException();
    return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0));
}
```

Input : 0060CE5601D6CE01

Output : 31-10-2013 06:20:48